# Find Total Votes a User has on their Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the [thumbs_up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) gem to get votes(likes) on Posts.

I have a page for each user's statistics and one of the statistics I'm trying to find shows how many people have voted (liked) the current_user's Posts. Here is what I have so far, I just need to include something that shows only the count that was on the current_users posts.

```
@vote_count = Vote.where("voteable_type = ?", "Update").count
# This shows all of the votes on all of the updates instead of ONLY the vote count of the current_user's updates
```

The Votes table has these columns

```
voteable_id
voteable_type
voter_id
voter_type
...
...
```

I think I have to associate the voteable_id to the current_user's `update_id` but I can't figure it out.

**Vote Model**

```
scope :for_voter, lambda { |*args| where(["voter_id = ? AND voter_type = ?", args.first.id, args.first.class.base_class.name]) }
scope :for_voteable, lambda { |*args| where(["voteable_id = ? AND voteable_type = ?", args.first.id, args.first.class.base_class.name]) }
scope :recent, lambda { |*args| where(["created_at > ?", (args.first || 2.weeks.ago)]) }
scope :descending, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }

belongs_to :voteable, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :voter, :polymorphic => true

attr_accessible :vote, :voter, :voteable if ActiveRecord::VERSION::MAJOR < 4


# Comment out the line below to allow multiple votes per user.
validates_uniqueness_of :voteable_id, :scope => [:voteable_type, :voter_type, :voter_id]
```

**Edit**

```
# user.rb
has_many :updates


# update.rb
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: How is relationship between user and vote setup?  Also how do you know which vote is like?

Comment: In the view you can tell by `@update.votes.count` so in the database for `Votes`, there is a boolean column for `:vote`. And the way it's setup with this gem is in the model, if a model is voteable you would put `acts_as_voteable` and for the user model would you would `acts_as_voter`. But I assume a `user has_many :votes` and `votes belong_to :user` and `updates has_many :votes`

Comment: Check the update to my question for `Vote` model

Comment: Doesn't `user.votes.where('voteable_type = ? and vote = ?', 'Update', true).count` give you what you need?  This will give you count of upvotes.

Comment: This gives the count of how many updates the current_user has upvoted. I need the number of upvotes on the current_user's updates.

Comment: can you show the associations of your Post model?

Comment: is an update what you call a Post?

Comment: Yea, sorry. As long as I can get the fundamental part of the query, I can interchange model names, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
user.updates.joins(:votes).where(votes: { vote: true }).count
```

Comment: `ERROR:  column updates.voteable_type does not exist`.

Comment: Weird. Looks like my comment got deleted? Another 5 hours to go until I can reward the bounty.